# Installing sDNA in QGIS for Mac?

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, sdna

How do I install sDNA in QGIS for mac?

Every time I try to do it the following message appears.

[image]

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 2):

The QGIS plugin is just a bridge that calls sDNA from QGIS; you also need to install [sDNA itself](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna).

That said, unfortunately there is no mac version of sDNA yet. This may change in future, in the meantime some Mac users run sDNA using Parallels.